# sharepoint adding extra slash when creating a subfolder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

when i am trying to create a folder inside a folder (sub-folder)
SharePoint adding an extra '/' and failing to create folder.

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" RootFolder="https://mysite.com/testing/sites/123/" ListVersion="1" ViewName="" xmlns="">
      <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
        <Field Name="ID">New</Field>
        <Field Name="BaseName">123-test</Field>
        <Field Name="Title">123-test</Field>
        <Field Name="ContentType">Folder</Field>
      </Method>
    </Batch>
```

getting the ErrorCode0x8107026f.

Comment: did you try to remove the '/' at the end of the url "https://mysite.com/testing/sites/123"? could you please tell me what URl Sharepoint to create

Comment: if i delete / at end it works fine.
share point creating a URI "https://mysite.com/testing/sites/123//123-test"
error Text is
"This operation can only be performed on a file; https://mysite.com/testing/sites/123//123-test is folder"

Comment: so it solved the issue?

Comment: for all my remaining sites this issue not happening with the same format..
for this site alone happening i want to know what is root cause for this issue...

Comment: i could not get what you trying to say? in above two URI, you have "//" after 123...

Comment: the sharepoint seems adding an extra slash, i am not sending double slashes. for all my sites the above request worked perfectly, but only for one site there is an extra slash as been adding by sharepoint itslef.

Comment: SO you saying, only in one scenario where you put slash after 123 then sharepoint throws the error but on rest of site colelction its worked fine....i am sure you create sub folder inside a folder on all sites